# Как правильно запретить обратный слэш с помощью preg_match?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Написал такой код:

```
$name = "5\f/f\f";
preg_match("~\\~i",$name,$mb);
print_r($mb);
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '~' found
```

Нужно запретить все слэши (и обратный и обычный, чтобы нельзя было вводить например url адрес)

Для обычного слэша написал так:

```
$name = "5\f/f\f";
preg_match("~\/~i",$name,$mb);
print_r($mb);
```

С ним проблем нет, но почему обратный слэш выдает ошибку, как правильно написать так, чтобы запретить и обратный и обычный слэш?

Comment: проэкранировать его?

Comment: вы только один слеш вставили, а его самого то же надо экранировать `\\\\\`

Comment: Хорошо, но возникает другой вопрос: почему здесь: $name = "5\f/f\f"; результат пустой? Обратный слэш же есть. Или в данном примере \f не считается за обратный слэш?

Comment: Не считается, `\f` - символ перевода страницы.

Comment: Вспомнил, сейчас двойную кавычку заменил одинарной (для переменной $name), тогда уже все верно, обратный слэш сейчас ищет

Comment: Осталось понять 2 вещи: 1. зачем в регулряках используется флаг `i` (поиск без учета регистра), он замедляет работу а больших и маленьких слешей не бывает. 2. зачем вообще используются регулярки, если есть гораздо более быстрые обычные строковые функции, например `strpbrk()` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpbrk.php

Comment: `i` и регулярки - не используйте там где не надо